# Getting value out of the resultset while loop

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using spring framework and below is a data access object implementation code for the method `getemployeeDetails`

As shown below, in the console, I can see the value getting printed from the following statement :

`System.out.println(employeeRecord.getEmployeeValue()); // Prints the value`

I am wondering, how can I get this value out of this method so that I can use it in another SQL statement `selectEmployeeInfo_SQL` below 
for the column `emp_value` which has hard coded value of `2` right now as shown below. I need to use the `selectEmployeeInfo_SQL` statement in another method(which I haven't mentioned below) in the same class.

```
  public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao
    {
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
        {       
            jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);                                    
        }

    public List<ShowDescription>  getemployeeDetails(String empID) throws DaoException
        {


            DataSource ds = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
            ResultSet rs2 = null;
            List<ShowDescription> employeeValue = new ArrayList<ShowDescription>();

            try {
                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(selectValueSQL);
                pstmt2.setString(1, empID);                 

                rs2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();            
                while(rs2.next()) {             
                    ShowDescription employeeRecord = new ShowDescription(); 
                    employeeRecord.setEmployeeValue(rs2.getString("value"));
                    employeeValue.add(employeeRecord);
                    System.out.println("I am inside getemployeeDetails method to get the Value");
                    System.out.println(employeeRecord.getEmployeeValue()); // Prints the value 

            } catch(Throwable th) {
                //some code
            } finally {
                // Closing all resources here
            }       

            return employeeValue;
        }   





        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

        }
        private String selectValueSQL = "SELECT * FROM DATABASEONE.empdetails WHERE emp_id = ? ";

        private String selectEmployeeInfo_SQL = "SELECT * FROM DATABASETWO.companydetails WHERE emp_value = 2";


        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    }
```

Here is the code for `ShowDescription` class in case needed for reference :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

import abc.def.project.json.Views;

public class ShowDescription {

    // Adding getters and setters 
    public String getEmployeeValue() {
        return employeeValue;
    }
    public void setEmployeeValue(String employeeValue) {
        this.employeeValue = employeeValue;
    }




    //Declaring variables for getting value
    @JsonView(Views.Normal.class)
    private String employeeValue;


}
```

Comment: "how can I get this value out of this method..." <- The fact that the printing happens inside a while loop would suggest that we are not talking about one value but multiple values. If it is allways just one value I would like to know why you are using a loop to print it at all.

Comment: Hmm, yes, it's only one value always. Maybe I should remove the loop then. Still, would I be able to get the value out of the method?

Comment: whats the issue? why can't you call this method inside the other method and have this ,method return the value you want?

Comment: @isaace How can I have that value in this SQL statement `private String selectEmployeeInfo_SQL = "SELECT * FROM DATABASETWO.companydetails WHERE emp_value = <<the VALUE SHOULD BE HERE>>";`. This is outside the method.

Comment: @Dan you cannot do that but you can still use the string in your method and add more to it. make the string static and in your method you can write selectEmployeeInfo_SQL + " the value from the other method"

Comment: @isaace Not sure if I would be able to call the `getemployeeDetails` method from another method in the same class in this case because in the Data Access Object, I have two different methods defined and the `getemployeeDetails` method is connecting to different database and another method is connecting to different database. I also have two separate beans defined in my controller class for each of these two methods so that I can connect to two different databases.